# Ya'akov claiming to be Esav - the Anochi versus Ani

Tags: commentaries, rashi, parashat-toldot

As Yakov presents the food that he has prepared for Yitzchok in order to receive the blessings, he says: אָנֹכִי עֵשָׂו בְּכֹרֶךָ - Genesis 27:19.

Rashi comments that what Yakov was really saying was: "I am the one" [who is bringing the food to you], [and] Eisav [is] your first born, thus separating the statement of Ya'akov of anochi, I, from Esav bichorecha, Esav is your firstborn (in response to Yitzchak’s query of his identity).

I liked the interpretation and I found an explanation on the matter:

> The problem: From where did Rashi derive this interpretation? What led
> Rashi away from the more simpler and obvious interpretation that Yakov
> was saying "I am Eisav your first born" in order to trick Yitzchok so
> he may receive the brochos.
>
> The solution : The Taamim (cantillations) are divided into two groups.
> One that warrants a pause after them and another that lead intos and
> connects the current word to the following word. The Taam on the word
> "Anochi" is a Pashta which is a cantillation or Taam that places a
> pause or comma after it. The following two words "Eisav Bechorecha"
> Eisav your firstborn, is punctuated with the Taam of Zakef Koton a
> Taam that joins the two words together as if there is no pause between
> them.
>
> In essence the Taam divides these words into two statements. The words
> following the punctuation of the Taam are saying I am, followed by an
> independent statement "Eisav your first born" with a comma or pause
> after the word I. The words Eisav your first born are also according
> to the Taam to be read as a statement on it's own. Therefore Rashi,
> following the Taam, understood Yakov to be saying two statements "
> Anochi" I am, meaning: I have brought the food, and a second statement
> that "Eisav Bechorecha" Eisav is your first born.

But afterwards - after I read this, and also about the difference between ani and anochi [see here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64742/difference-between-%D7%90%D6%B2%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%99-and-%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%A0%D6%B9%D7%9B%D6%B4%D7%99/65382#65382) - I came across verse 24 in which Ya'akov answers the words  אַתָּה זֶה בְּנִי עֵשָׂו with  אָנִי.

What I would like to know is, if we follow Rashi's comment, how one should explain this?; whether or not Ya'akov consciously weighs his words in Genesis 27:19 or whether he just twice claims to be Esau.

Comment: *Al pi sod* Yaakov took over Esav's task of correcting *olam hazeh* and therefore acquired his *neshama* and therefore he was indeed *Esav*.